# Rounding off result in java

Tags: java

Hello i am making a program that computes the frequency distribution and i have a problem in getting the number of class because I am going to use this in frequency distribution... the result of # of class is...

 
6.286797971382275 and it is correct but...

i want to round this off to 7...

how am i going to do that? thanks

```
    String []values = ( inputValues.getText().toString().split(","));
            int[] convertedValues = new int[values.length];
            txtTotalNum.setText(Integer.toString(values.length));


            //calculate for the minimum and maximum number
            Arrays.sort(convertedValues);

            int max=convertedValues[0];
            for(int i=0;i<convertedValues.length;i++){
                convertedValues[i] =Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
                if(convertedValues[i]>max){
                    max=convertedValues[i];
                }
            }

            int min = convertedValues[0];
             double classes=0;
            for(int i=0;i<convertedValues.length;i++){
                convertedValues[i] =Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
                if(convertedValues[i]<min){
                    min=convertedValues[i];

                }
            }

            txtMinimum.setText(Integer.toString(min));
            txtMaximum.setText(Integer.toString(max));


            //calculate for the range

            int range=max - min;
            txtRange.setText(Integer.toString(range));

            //calculate for the # of classes

                classes=1+3.3*Math.log10(convertedValues.length);

              Classes.setText(Double.toString(classes));
```

Comment: Why don't you use something like `Math.ceil()` ?

Comment: Did you try `Math.ceil()`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Math.ceil()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29)

```
Math.ceil(6.286797971382275);
```

This is what it is going to return you,

> The smallest (closest to negative infinity) floating-point value that
>   is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a
>   mathematical integer.

Read the API before using it.

Comment: "Read the API before using it.", ha! We can hope, we can hope

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Math class.

Math.ceil()

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `Math.ceil()`. It will [round up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) your number to the nearest whole value. Note,  it still returns a double.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.
        double dval = 6.286797971382275 ;
        System.out.println(dval);
        System.out.println(Math.ceil((dval)));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DecimalFormat` beside `Math.ceil()`

```
double input = 6.286797971382275;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");

df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
String output = df.format(input);

System.out.println("output  : " + output);
```